# Java - Using only .substring procedure to find multiple words within a string

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to use utilize a space " " to separate words within a String that a user inputs. For this example, the user input String might be "Random Access Memory" or "Java Development Kit." Regardless of the entered string, the space will separate each word. In addition to this, I cannot use .split or an array, since those are the most common solutions I have found thus far. Only utilizing .substring is allowed. In my failed attempts, I have only been capable of obtaining the first inputted word (ex. "Random"), but cannot separate the second and third words (ex. "Access Memory"). I'm not going to publish my failed attempts, but am asking if you could please provide the code for separating both the second and third words entered? Thanks.

P.S. I know this is used to create acronyms, I can do that part, just need to identify each substring.

```
  import javax.swing.*;
  public class ThreeLetterAcronym
  {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {

        String wordsInput, initialInput;
        String first = "";
        String second = "";
        String third = "";

        int firstWord;
        int secondWord;
        int wordLength;
        int secondWordLength;

        char c;

        wordsInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter three words");
        initialInput = wordsInput;
        wordLength = wordsInput.length();
        firstWord = 0;
        secondWord = 0;


        while(firstWord < wordsInput.length()) 
              {
               if(wordsInput.charAt(firstWord) == ' ') 
               {
                  first = wordsInput.substring(0,firstWord);
                  second = wordsInput.substring(firstWord + 1, wordsInput.length());
  //I know that this is the spot where the last two words are displayed in the output, this is
  //the closest I have been to displaying anything relevant.
                  firstWord = wordsInput.length();

               }
                  ++firstWord;

              }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Original phrase was: " 
           + initialInput + "\nThree letter acronym is: " + first + second);
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to separate in words without (strangely) using Spring.split:

```
String myString = "Random Access Memory";

int begin = 0;
int end;
while((end = myString.indexOf(" ", begin)) != -1) {
    System.out.println(myString.substring(begin, end));
    begin = end + 1;
}
System.out.println(myString.substring(begin));
```

Comment: so the string is a user input, not a pre-defined string. "Random Access Memory" was an example of a user input... as indicated int the text above the code.

Comment: @user3304613 A String is a String, doesn't matter where it comes from

Comment: In an attempt to use a variation of the code above, it did not produce expected results. My question asked if someone would be able to assist in the already provided code to produce the outcome detailed in the header text?

Comment: Be specific about the case in which it didn't work. If it worked, please accept this answer by clicking on the `(tick symbol)`. It will help people with similar issues to select their answer with ease next time. `Upvoting` and `accepting` an answer motivates people to answer more.

Answer (score 0):

```
       String tmp = wordsInput.trim();

       int spaceIndex = tmp.indexOf(" ");
       first = tmp.substring(0,spaceIndex);
       tmp = tmp.substring(spaceIndex+1);
       tmp = tmp.trim();

       spaceIndex = tmp.indexOf(" ");
       second = tmp.substring(0, spaceIndex);
       tmp = tmp.trim();

       third = tmp.substring(spaceIndex+1);
```

You can use a loop to improve the code. I hope that will be helpful.